# Get a trait object reference from a vector

Tags: rust

I'm struggling to get an element from a `Vec` that is a reference with a lifetime. I've simplified my code down to this:

```
pub trait Runnable {}

pub struct RunList<'a> {
    runnables: Vec<&'a mut Runnable>,
}

impl<'a> RunList<'a> {
    pub fn get(&self, id: usize) -> &'a mut Runnable {
        self.runnables[id]
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0332f027d85350e749b02d8015cb3a53&version=stable)

which produces this error:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter in function call due to conflicting requirements
 --> src/main.rs:9:9
  |
9 |         self.runnables[id]
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 8:5...
 --> src/main.rs:8:5
  |
8 | /     pub fn get(&self, id: usize) -> &'a mut Runnable {
9 | |         self.runnables[id]
10| |     }
  | |_____^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
 --> src/main.rs:9:9
  |
9 |         self.runnables[id]
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the impl at 7:1...
 --> src/main.rs:7:1
  |
7 | impl<'a> RunList<'a> {
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  = note: ...so that the expression is assignable:
          expected &'a mut Runnable + 'a
             found &mut Runnable + 'a
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, remove the lifetime parameter `'a` from the type of the return value of `get`:

```
pub trait Runnable {}

pub struct RunList<'a> {
    runnables: Vec<&'a mut Runnable>,
}

impl<'a> RunList<'a> {
    pub fn get(&mut self, id: usize) -> &mut Runnable {
        self.runnables[id]
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

This gets you to the underlying problem:

```
error[E0389]: cannot borrow data mutably in a `&` reference
 --> src/main.rs:9:9
  |
9 |         self.runnables[id]
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ assignment into an immutable reference
```

`self.runnables[id]` borrows `&'a mut Runnable` immutably and dereferences it implicitly. You can't move `&'a mut Runnable` out of this immutable borrow. Instead, you can mutably reborrow the runnable which requires a mutable borrow of `self`:

```
impl<'a> RunList<'a> {
    pub fn get(&mut self, id: usize) -> &mut Runnable {
        &mut *self.runnables[id]
    }
}
```

---

To understand what's exactly going on here one should read up on: [What is the return type of the indexing operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27879161)

```
pub fn get(&mut self, id: usize) -> &mut Runnable {
    self.runnables[id]
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
pub fn get(&mut self, id: usize) -> &mut Runnable {
    let r: &&mut (Runnable + 'a)  = self.runnables.index(id);
    *r
}
```

`index` returns an immutable reference to `&'a mut Runnable`, which is of type `&&mut (Runnable + 'a)`. Returning `*r` does not work, because you can't move the mutable reference<sup>1</sup> out of the borrowed content and also data in an immutable reference can't be borrowed mutably (`&mut**r` does not work). Therefore, you need the version of `index` which grants mutable access to the indexed element: `index_mut`

```
pub fn get(&mut self, id: usize) -> &mut Runnable {
    let r: &mut &'a mut (Runnable + 'a)  = self.runnables.index_mut(id);
    *r
}
```

This works, because `*r` actually reborrows the `Runnable` inside mutably (`&mut**r`). In contrast to the case with the immutable reference `r` above, mutably borrowing the data inside the mutable reference `r` is perfectly fine. When performing `&mut**r` the parameter `'a` gets lost in the process of dereferencing. So, returning  `&'a mut Runnable` instead of `&mut Runnable` does not work here.

Finally, `&mut *self.runnables[id]` tells the compiler to implicitly resolve to `*self.runnables.index_mut(id)` instead of `*self.runnables.index(id)`. `*&mut self.runnables[id]` would also work.

---

<sup>1 <sub>Mutable references are not `Copy`. If you changed all `&'a mut Runnable` in your code to `&'a Runnable`, it would compile, because immutable references are `Copy`</sub></sup>

Comment: OK, thanks! I don't understand it all, but it's fixed my problem (or moved it somewhere else... :-) ), so thanks again.

Comment: @AndrewMackenzie I added a more detailed explanation. It should make things clear.